# Java declaration of global string variables

Tags: java, global-variables

I am writing a server program and a client program. I named the server code file server.java. The client runs from a different machine. One of the things the client can do is upload files to the server. I want the server to store the uploaded files in a folder which resides in the same directory as the server.java program file. So I used the following code:

```
String server_files_location = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

This did work. However I have to declare this variable separately in all the different classes I am writing. I want to make this a global string variable so that I dont have to declare this every time I add a new class or method.

So at the beginning of the program I tried:

```
public static String server_files_location = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

This gives me an error saying `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object`.

How else can I get this variable to be accessible globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class literal from the class you're declaring the variable in.

```
public static String server_files_location =
    YourClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Consider making the variable `final` if it's a constant and won't ever change.  Additionally, the normal Java variable naming convention would say to name the variable in camel case, e.g. `serverFilesLocation`, or if it's a constant, in ALL CAPS, e.g. `SERVER_FILES_LOCATION`.

Comment: How would you declare `DataInputStream` or `DataOutputStream`or `BufferedReader` globally?

Answer (score 0):

delete `static` in your declaration of the variable.  All the instances will be able to access one instance's copy of it if both the variable and the instance in question are public.